# Why does Mono distort the rendering of aspx web pages on Raspberry PI 3?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, web-server

I noticed recently that Mono(version 4.4.2) distorts the rendering of  aspx web pages on Raspberry PI 3 running Raspbian as shown below. When I setup apache, mod_mono_server4 and Mono(version 4.4.2) on Ubuntu 16.04 with  x86_64 processor, I noticed that aspx web pages do not undergo distortion.

Why does this happen and how could we fix it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a couple of screen grabs so we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: @Steve Robillard, May I upload a couple of screenshots tomorrow at  7 a.m? I cannot go into the office on weekends. Thank you.

Comment: @Steve Robillard, I just realized that uploading a couple of screenshots could jeopardize our customer relationships and our competitive  advantage. What other information may I provide regarding  the distortion of the rendering of aspx web pages on the Raspberry PI 3?

Comment: Without a picture I don't know that anyone will be able to answer your question. Why can't you blur or obfiscate the sensitive info?

Comment: @Steve Robillard, Thank you for your reply. May I email you the screenshot?

Comment: @Steve Robillard, I just uploaded a screen "grab" of the distorted webpage image. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered yesterday that the distortion occurs because the Chrome browser throws an HTTP error 400 or 403 when it encounters 192.168.10.31/Content/xyz.css or 192.168.10.31/scripts/abc.js. The css files control how the aspx webpages are presented.

I diagnosed this error by using curl -I  192.168.10.31/Content/xyz.css .

I solved this problem by using an AliasMatch regex file-path|directory-path with alternation as follows:

AliasMatch aspx file path regex| css file path regex| js file regex  filepath/$2/$3.$4

preceded by

Alias /Content   /home/uw/DevelopmentX64/HVR-Web-App/Content

and to specifically prevent the HTTP error 403 Forbidden which one can find in /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
<Directory "/home/uw/DevelopmentX64">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

 and 

<Directory "/home/uw/DevelopmentX64/HVR-Web-App">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I will fill in the details at 8:00 A.M today.

Comment: @Steve Robillard, Thank you for offering to help solve this difficult problem .Please verify the correctness of this answer when you have time.

Comment: I know you have client privacy issues, but it is not apparent from the picture what is wrong. As an aid to others who come after you may I suggest you upload a screenshot from the working version as a comparison.

Comment: @Steve Robillard, You suggest a good idea. At 8:00 A.M. today, I will upload a screenshot from the working version as a comparison.

Comment: @Steve Robillard, My manager will not allow uploading a screenshot from the working version as a comparison.

Comment: Then may I suggest that you edit your original question and change distort to missing styles or stylesheet. One of the reasons I asked for the original pic was  because when I read distort I was imagining a box that was not rectilinear.

Comment: @Steve Robillard, Thank you for your answer. On the Raspberry PI 3, I found distortion occurs because the Chrome browser throws an HTTP error 400 or 403 when it encounters 192.168.10.31/Content/xyz.css or 192.168.10.31/scripts/abc.js. How about the Ubuntu 16.04 desktop case? I recall I could render the aspx pages correctly without adding the additional Alias and AliasMatch alternating regular expressions to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf? Is that possible?

Comment: It might be, but wouldn't fixing the networking issue the better solution? You may be able to do something as simple as adding an entry to the /etc/hosts file.

Comment: @Steve Robillard, Thank you for your answer. What does the networking issue with /etc/hosts have to do with the missing 192.168.10.31/Content/xyz.css or 192.168.10.31/scripts/abc.js?

Comment: I am assuming that the server is the part of the URL that can't be found. Somewhere you have a misconfiguration either in your app path or in the host if you are returning a 404. If it is the host you can add a host entry and possible a route. If the in the path part then fix it in your app path (perhaps by adding a dev and productionconfig). Doing things like an alias are quick but not exactly clean nor portable.